# Listening For Events Outside Of Tab

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am building an extension for Google Play Music and I'm wondering if there is a way that you can inject a piece of code into the web page that will listen to events on every window. Not just the browser. So if I want to pause the music and I am editing code in Notepad++, I would press a certain key combination, my computer would pick that up, and it would pause the music.

Is there a certain function that listens to everything you do no matter which window I'm in or an extension that allows me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way for a web application to capture events which aren't directed at its window.

(Consider the implications, anyways -- what if two sites you were visiting both tried to register the same hotkey?)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this kind of functionality by using socket.io.

- Whenever page loads, you need to connect that user with a socket connection and bind userID with it.
- If user presses pause button, You need to emit an event (Lets say pauseEvent).
- As Server receives pauseEvent, It sends instruction of pausing to all connected sockets of that userID.
- Player will be paused from each tab since each  will receive pauseEvent response and will execute the same callback.

**EDIT:**

Listening shortcut from One window will fire same sequence of algorithm and will affect to all.